# Oracle Content Delivery CreateTridionSYSUser.sql errors

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, database, oracle, oracle-12c

I have an Oracle 12.1.0.2 DB running on RHEL 7. As I understand it, the first step of setting up a CD delivery database is to create the TRIDION_SYS user.

When I log in to the db via sqlplus with "CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA" and run the "@CreateTridionSYSUser.sql" script, the script fails with errors stemming from an error "ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name". What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else stuck with this, here's the solution.

Oracle 12c introduces multitenancy. With this architecture the Tridion Content Delivery database must be set up in the pluggable database rather than the container database that is the default when you first connect via sqlplus.

To switch to the pluggable database you will need to log in "sys as sysdba" and use the command `alter session set container=pdborcl;` to switch to the pluggable DB. You can then use the CD installation scripts, including the tridion_sys set up script to run the installation process.

Comment: Hi Mark, that was the suggestion given the DBA stack exchange link that I mentioned in my answer, to alter the session. What other information you have added in your answer which makes it different?

Comment: Hi Vipin, the stackoverflow answer that you linked to suggests that changing the session container does not work and does not allow a change to another user account after running. I found this question myself whilst trying to figure this out and skipped past it because it seemed not to resolve the problem.The suggestion to prefix the username with 'c##' is not relevant in this case as it would make the tridion_sys user an admin of all pluggable databases.

Comment: Well, first was creation was your core issue which should have been solved with alter session and infact thats how you solved it with the same command mentioned in the link "alter session set container=PDBORCL;"! Second, pluggable container concept was also explained the link I had added in my answer. As I said it is Oracle specific error, nothing related to Tridion so can't give a detailed answer as I am not a DBA :)

Comment: Searching for the error I found the same references. I see that this answer includes the specific "what worked for me" answer, derived from those sources, which Vipin also answered with. I see both answers as valuable for giving context and background.

Answer (score 2):

This is an Oracle specific error (not related to Tridion) and it occurs because of the scope/container where you are trying to create the user in the Oracle DB. You should try option mentioned in the below link which should resolve the issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60806/oracle-12c-create-user

Couple of other links describing the issue and alternate solutions

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_65096_create_user_12c_without_c_prefix.htm

http://dbatricksworld.com/ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-and-ora-65049-creation-of-local-user-or-role-is-not-allowed-in-cdbroot/